# In Excel how to fill remaining cell with "~" after name for a specific character size of 15

Tags: excel

In Excel 2003 I have a positional file and I want to space fill with a delimiter of "~" for 15 total characters. How can I ensure that each first name has exactly 15 characters prepended with "~" at the end for space fill.  I tried to do this in custom format mode, but it doesn't work correctly.

Examples:

```
SALLY~~~~~~~~~~
TOM~~~~~~~~~~~~
FRED~~~~~~~~~~~
```

etc...

Comment: What are you using to fill the file up?

Comment: Eventually what I want to do is export the entire file in a text file which has positional references for each field.  That's why I want to prepend all the squiggles.

Comment: Its a test data for now, but it will be sql 2000 for now, but we are moving to 2008r2 later.

Comment: do you have a query that you use to bring data from SQL 2000? If so, you can do this in the query itself `SELECT LEFT ('SALLY' + Replace (SPACE (15), ' ', '~'), 15)`.  Of course, instead of `'SALLY'` put the NAME column

Comment: Also, you don't need to bring it to excel to export to a text file - you can create a view and then use SSMS to export to CSV file

Comment: I intend to use a view, the reason I'm using excel is for prototyping the specs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative;

```
=A1 & REPT("~", 15 - LEN(A1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the names are in column A

Put this in cell A2 `=LEFT(A1&"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~",15)` and drag it down

I'm just adding fifteen squiggles to the right and then cutting it down to the leftmost 15 characters to give you equal widths.